# MVC: no views found, no locations were searched. Now why is that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, viewengine

The image of a login page (clickable image): [image: http://i.snag.gy/sHPyQ.jpg]

Is it seems (though the debug viewer), the `ViewEngines` are both (razor+webforms, im using the first) there, in the `ViewEngines` collection, and them both can **find** the views (manually) and display them, also tried manually.

So why is that they cannot do it on their own? This is simply an action method, nothing more:

```
public ViewResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

### Major Update

I have overridden the `OnResultExecuting` method:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
    {
        if (((ViewResult)filterContext.Result).ViewEngineCollection.Count == 0)
        {
            ((ViewResult)filterContext.Result).ViewEngineCollection.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
        }
    }

    base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

And it turned out that every time and every view I do now need to add new `IViewEngine` to a `ViewResult`. Now why is that so? Even if the `ViewEngines.Engines` collection is not empty?

#### Minor update.

The `ViewEngineCollection` stopped being empty at some point of **idling**.

Comment: What is the controller and action set as for the Default MapRoute in your RouteConfig.cs file?

Comment: DO you have any areas?both can find the views (manually) and display them ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewEngineCollection` stopped being empty at some point of **idling**.

This only might refer to some ASP.NET caching of old assemblies which was not for some reason updated by the new ones. This happens from time to time, and I have to clear the cache in order for some new code to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a master page defined?

If you have a _ViewStart.chstml file in the root of your solution then it is possible the engine is trying to load a master page to combine with your view.

To skip the master page tell your view to not use a master page.  Add the following to the View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

or make sure that the master page referenced in the _viewStart.cshtml file exists.

Comment: Yes I do have a master page, and its path is correctly defined in `ViewStart` file.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have a correct `ViewEngines` configured (or none).

Try adding to view engines manually to identify if there is a configuration error somewhere.

Add something like this to `Application_Start()` method of `Global.asax`.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
   ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
   // Other code
}
```

This should initialise the Razor view engine, and if as a result mvc starts searching locations, you have somehow turned off razor in the configuration.

Comment: I did it, but it did not help me. As I claimed before, there are both engines in the collection at the moment the `return View()` line is hit by the execution.